# Using a Regular Expression to capture a word that contains a letter at a specific position?

Tags: regex, capture

I'm looking for a regex expression that will highlight all words in a text document that contain a letter at a specific position that I specify in the expression.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which language? Python, Bash...? Provide an example of what you want to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `\b[[:alpha:]]{X}L` where `X` is the character position and `L` is the letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
\b\w{A}B\w*\b
```

where A is the the position - 1 where you want the character to appear, and **B** is the character you want.

for example if you want to highlight all the words that have the "x" character in the 3 position the you would use `\b\w{2}x\w*\b` (2 because the desired position is 3 so `3 - 1 = 2`)

check this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OYq2dd/1) to see it working and play with it